# Saving a document in MongoDB without clobbering previous partial updates to a sub document

Tags: .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Suppose I have a model like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public Guid Id { get;set;}
    public string Title { get;set;}
    public List<Comment> Comments { get;set;}
}
```

When saved to Mongo using the official driver, Comments will end up as a embedded sub document. I don't want someone adding a comment to require saving the entire document, so I wrote an atomic partial update method:

```
public void AddComment(Item item, Comment comment)
{           
    Collection.Update(
        Query.EQ("_id", item.Id), 
        Update.AddToSet("Comments", 
        BsonValue.Create(comment)));
}
```

However, I am not sure how to specify to the Mongo driver that "Comments" is maintained using these in-place updates, and shouldn't be persisted if calling Save() on the parent document.

Is there a attribute I could decorate the property with? Or will I be forced to write a update method that specifies all of the properties I want to update by hand.

Comment: Are you thinking of BsonIgnore? If you put that on your Comments list it'll be ignore by MongoDB.

Comment: @PawBaltzersen: If you will put BsonIgnore serializer will ignore Comments during serializtion/deserialization, but he need to ignore it only during serialization.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify [`ShouldSerializeXyz`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial#CSharpDriverSerializationTutorial-IgnoringamemberbasedonaShouldSerializeXyzmethod) method in your item class like this:

```
public bool ShouldSerializeComments() {
    return false;
}
```

Then driver will never serialize comments when you will save object.

Or another option is set comments to null before save and use [BsonIgnoreIfNull](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial#CSharpDriverSerializationTutorial-Ignoringnullvalues) attribute

```
public class Item
{
    ...
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public List<Comment> Comments { get;set;}
}

...

obj.Comments = null;
collection.Save(obj);
```